# older version of flutter plugins that compatible with SDK 31

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, flutter-plugin, url-launcher, geolocator

I just finished developing an app but when I compile to apk the following error appear

> Warning: The plugin geolocator_android requires Android SDK version 33.
> For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
> Warning: The plugin google_api_headers requires Android SDK version 32.
> For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
> Warning: The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 33.
> For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.

my plugins at pubspec.yaml:[image]

Any recommendation to rollback these 3 problematic plugin version that fits SDK 31?

Thanks.